# Spring data doesn't get eager

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm migrating my code to use the repositories, when I try to get an `User` with `findOne(Integer)` I got the user but the `userRoles` are empty.

Repository:

```
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass = User.class, idClass = Integer.class)
public interface UserRepository {
   User findOne(Integer id);
   ...
}
```

User:

```
public class User implements UserDetails{
   ...
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
   private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>(0);
   ...
}
```

UserRole:

```
public class UserRole implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer userRoleId;
    @Column(length = 45, nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure User row really has UserRole?, in my case Spring Data respect EAGER/LAZY fetch

Comment: Yes it has. was the first thing that I check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a `join` defining my own query with:

```
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass = User.class, idClass = Integer.class)
public interface UserRepository {
    @Query("from User u join u.userRoles where u.id = ?1")
    User findOne(Integer id);
       ...
}
```